# Is it ok to add meta tag in head using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo, meta

I want to add meta tag conditionally in an HTML page, i am not sure if it is ok to do so or not using jQeruy ready even. The example is given bellow.

```
var myHost = window.location.host;
if(myHost.startsWith("techstag")) {
   $("head").append('<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">');
}
```

Comment: Do not add  any `<meta>` tag by `jQuery`, that's all!

Comment: @Pedram Can i write it using pure javascript like this.

<head>
<script>
document.write('<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">');
</script>
</head>

Comment: No, the only way is write it in `<head>` tag. because you are trying to add `noindex,nofollow`, so if you add this tag after page load, by js, jq or etc.. crawlers ,robots, not read it!

Comment: @Pedram Thanks for the help, it makes sense as the crawlers read the page they won't find the meta tag until it is appended in the page after the js is executed. i had doubt so it is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

In short, it may or may not work.

It would work in the sense you'll see the meta tag in page when you inspect it.

But, if you are intending to do this for **SEO purposes**

1. For the most part, it won't work, as most web crawlers do not execute javascript while scanning the web pages.
2. It will work for crawlers that do execute JS (e.g. Google's)

Comment: it makes sense as the crawlers read the page they won't find the meta tag until it is appended in the page after the js is executed. i had doubt so it is clear now. Thanks!